# How to listen to Phone Alarm in flutter App?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, mobile-application

/*I'll try to ask it in as simple a way as I can. If my app is running in foreground and, My phone alarm rings at that very moment, is there any way I can call a function/perform an operation when this happens?

My App is open at any random time alarm rings*/

`` (if alarm_Rings) { `// How do I do this bit via dart code?`
 sample()
}
void sample() { // Any random function
// Some code to perform ``
}`

Comment: There's no way to tell if an alarm rings, because an alarm ringing isn't a feature of the OS.  The clock app is just another app.  There's no way to know why an app is playing a sound and that it's because it's an alarm.  Now if you just want to lower your volume if another app is trying to make a noise, that's called audio ducking and it is a feature of the OS.